# rails 7 ActionController unknown format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My rails 7 app is getting an error unknown format for `format.js` So then what do I need to install, rails-ujs, jquery, ... which npm package or which rails gem I built this site with jsbundling esbuild and cssbundling bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to listen to a format.js request with something like this in your controller:

```rb
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

Then you would probably want to have a template with the `js.erb` template in the views folder.

But be aware that this isn't the preferred way in Rails 7.
`Format.js` responses was in the Rails-UJS days the way to go.

These days you can use TurboStream for asynchron request.

If you can't use Turbo, you have to install the `@rails/ujs` npm package and initialize it with:

```js
import Rails from '@rails/ujs';
Rails.start();
```

Comment: Thanks That works I tried to do it with format.turbo_streams but I couldn't get it to work so I'm using @rails/ujs I'm actually following along with a stripe checkout tutorial written for rails 6 so the contents of create.js.erb are copied and pasted from stripe's docs I don't know what happens when I try to repsond format.turbo_streams